# Using file:// in the internet

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, file, security

I have [this webpage](https://learning.mycustomprograms.com/) for testing purpose, and I am using for `src` and `href` the `file-protocol`, like this:

```
file:///D:/Internet/TestPictures/air elemental , luftelementar.jpg
```

The idea behind is to

- save bandwidth, because the file is locally on my computer/mobile phone and does not need to be loaded later over the mobile network
- saving webspace(files are locally on my pc)
- Only I can see the files ?!(hopefully yes)

I have a few questions:

- is it risky to do it that way, because an attacker knows the folder structure on my pc ?
- why, doesn't the picture load initially like on my [local pc and NAS](http://imgur.com/TVTXhxt) ?

Thank you

Comment: You've published a site on the internet that's supposed to be used only by yourself and only from a given computer? What for?

Comment: If this were allowed in webpages, that'd be a pretty major security flaw. Imagine websites being able to see every file and photo on your local computer without even asking permission...

Comment: @Álvaro González actually its not that top secret, just pictures, I thought of saving webspace and using my webpage for searching.

Comment: @Luke Taylor I think there were such thing in the past where the website used an iframe and the path to the disk to trick the user on the web site and believe that the web site owner sees all of his local files(but it worked, of course only for the visitor of the page not the website owner)

Comment: You didn't understand me... A web site has two main features: it's multi-user and it can be reached from everywhere. Why build a single-user local site and host it in the internet? Why not just save it in your desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last question: For security reasons, any references to the local filesystem won't work when the page is delivered from another domain, at least not on modern browsers. If that weren't the case, then a maliciously crafted website would have access to your local files.

As for the other concerns, since browsers already cache data, relying on a file being your local system would only save the initial transfer, which is a negligible consequence. Having others know about your filesystem structure isn't good per se, but it's not inherently risky unless the attacker has access to your system. But all of this is pretty much moot since you won't be able to access the referenced file as soon as the page is delivered by anything other than the filesystem anyway.

Comment: Ok, but this wouldn't explain why it works on my NAS, when I just put a website on my NAS and all pictures(locally on my disk) and I could access it from all PC's ... ?

Comment: If your network drive is being accessed by the file:// protocol itself, then that's considered part of the same-origin policy by browsers. It's only once you start delivering the page by http that the policy comes into conflict.